# Pourquoi dit-on "avoir l'air de ..." ?

Tags: expressions

Je m'interroge sur le fait que l'on parle de l'air pour parler des apparences.  Après tout, si les apparences sont trompeuses, l'air n'est-il pas en général transparent ?

Pourquoi dit-on à la place de "sembler", "paraitre", "avoir l'apparence de" : "avoir l'air (de)" ? D'où cela vient-il ? Quel lien avec l'air et les apparences ?

Après quelques recherches de mon coté, je suis tombé sur le mot "débonnaire" qui signifie littéralement "de bonne aire", c'est à dire "de bonne souche" (*"souche"* dans le sens *"origine"* donc *"noble"*) ([voir définition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9bonnaire)).
Il semble donc que le mot "aire" soit ou fut lié à une notion de statut, de position. Et cela semble confirmé également par sa définition ([voir ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aire)), dont je cite le passage suivant:

> Soc. Bibliophiles, II, 284 et II, 285, ibid.); 2. début xiiies. masc.
>   « origine, souche » (Perceval, éd. Potvin, 13813, ibid. : ne set
>   encore noiant Ne dont il est ne de quel ere Qui fu son pere ne sa
>   mere); 1342 fém. de bonne aire (J. Bruyant, Chemin de Povreté et de
>   Richesse ds Le Ménagier, éd. qua supra, 11 b, ibid. : Soies courtois
>   et debonnaire Comme uns homs estrait de bonne aire); d'où 3. ca 1100
>   masc. « sorte, espèce » (Rol., éd. Bédier, 763 : malvais hom de put

J'y vois donc un rapport possible avec une formulation qui serait plutôt *"avoir l'**aire** de..."*, c'est-à-dire *"avoir les origines de"*. Dans l'hypothèse ou cela est vrai, on pourrait imaginer une utilisation cynique comme par exemple *"avoir l'aire d'un idiot"* (avoir les origines de l'idiotie) dont le mot *"aire"* aurait été déformé en *"air"* à l'usage. Mais je ne fais ici que des suppositions.

Answer (score 5):

C'est sous l'influence de l'italien que le mot « air » a pris le sens qu'il a dans l'expression « avoir l'air ».

Le latin *aer* a donné le mot français « air », qui désigne d'abord l'atmosphère avant de donner plus tard son nom au gaz qui compose l'atmosphère que nous respirons. Ce double sens existe toujours en français contemporain.

En italien ce mot latin *aer* a évolué en *aria*  qui désigne aussi bien l'atmosphère (comme en français) que l'ambiance. Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* * signale que le mot *aria* est employé en italien pour la première fois avec le sens d'« aspect », de « manière » par [Pétrarque](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9trarque), poète qui a influencé la Renaissance en France dès le XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle, quand l'expression est apparue en français. Un peu plus tardivement dans la Renaissance, le mot *aria* a été employé pour désigner une manière de chanter, sens qui a été repris aussi en français, « le chant est considéré comme une manière un « genre » musical.  »

Il n'est d'ailleurs pas difficile d'imaginer le glissement du sens du mot *air* qui a le sens d'« atmosphère », à celui d'« apparence », d'« aspect ». Quand je dis que « je vais respirer l'air de la campagne », je prends peut-être l'air au sens du gaz que je respire et je veux dire que je vais « aérer mes poumons », mais quand je dis que « je vais respirer l'air de la ville », je ne pense certainement pas à mes poumons mais à l'ambiance qui règne dans la ville et dont je vais m'imprégner, ce qui inclut aussi son aspect extérieur.

<sup>* Sous la direction d'Alain Rey, éditions Le Robert.</sup>

Comment: Merci pour votre apport pertinent. Je viens pour ma part d'éditer la question, où je fais l'hypothèse que air viendrait du latin area (aire). Qu'en pensez-vous ? Votre explication pourrait alors montrer comment l'usage aurait préféré "air" à "aire" par connotations avec "aria". Mais, je le répète, ce ne sont ici que des hypothèses de ma part.

Comment: @user2010913: Il y a confusion entre « aire » du latin *area* (qui a donné « débonnaire ») et *air* du latin *aer* qui a donné « air », « aria », etc...

Comment: [_āēr_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DA%3Aentry+group%3D27%3Aentry%3Daer) et [_ārĕa_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DA%3Aentry+group%3D71%3Aentry%3Darea).

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that air is generally transparent, it is also generally circulating and in constant motion (unless in a vacuum), which helps explain it's use in the English expression "up in the air" to mean "without foundation or actuality; uncertain; undecided; and unsettled," which meaning is also captured to a certain extent in French by the adverbial phrase "[en l'air](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/en%20l%27air)."

Although the above discussion might help explain why "air" doesn't have to mean only "transparent," it doesn't connect the word to "appearance," which is your question.

One non-etymologic (Laure has the etymology covered nicely) connection/explanation that I can think of comes from comparing and connecting the somewhat similar words (and their multiple meanings) "air" and "nature."

"Nature" can mean 1) one's characteristics/properties (appearance), but it can also mean 2) all the things surrounding us (humans) on Earth (including air).

"Air" can mean the natural substance surrounding us that we breath (connecting it to meaning #2 of "nature"), but it can also mean, as you note, one's general appearance (connecting it to meaning #1 of "nature").

"Air can also mean a melody, as noted by Iside and Laure, which reminds me of one of my favorite expressions: "[L'air ne fait pas la chanson,](http://www.linternaute.com/proverbe/3859/l-air-ne-fait-pas-la-chanson/)" which captures well, I think, the notion that appearances can be deceiving.

**Regarding your edit** concerning the possible connection between "air" and "aire" in French, I wouldn't dare to imply that the following applies to French, but according to several [legitimate?] sources of the etymology of **English** words, it is **probable** that the two relevant senses of the English word "air" (1-gas and 2-(appearance)impression/manner) actually came from **two different** source words (1-gas-from the [old?] French "air" and 2-(appearance)impression/manner-from the Old French "aire.")

> Origin (of the English word "air": (from [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/air))
>
> Middle English (in sense 1 of the noun): **from Old French air**, from
>   Latin aer, from Greek aēr, denoting the gas.
>
> sense 2 of the noun is from French air, **probably from Old French
>   aire** 'site, disposition', from Latin ager, agr- 'field' (influenced
>   by sense 1).
>
> sense 3 of the noun comes from Italian aria (see aria).
>
> 1. The main modern sense of air, ‘the invisible gaseous substance surrounding the earth’ entered English via Old French and Latin from
>      Greek aēr. Aerial (late 16th century), meaning ‘a rod or wire by which
>      signals are transmitted or received’ and ‘existing or happening in the
>      air’, comes from the same source, along with the Italian word aria
>      (early 18th century). Aerobic (late 19th century) is from aēr combined
>      with Greek bios ‘live’.
> 2. The senses of air ‘an impression or manner’ and ‘a condescending manner’ (as in she gave herself airs) are probably from a **completely
>      different word**, Old French **aire** ‘site, disposition’, which
>      derives from Latin ager ‘field’, the root of English words such as
>      agriculture (Late Middle English). Airy-fairy (mid 19th century)
>      ‘impractical and foolishly idealistic’, was originally used to mean
>      ‘delicate or light as a fairy’. The English poet Alfred, Lord Tennyson
>      ( 1809–1892), in his poem ‘Lilian’ ( 1830), described the subject as
>      ‘Airy, fairy Lilian, Flitting, fairy Lilian’. See also gas
>      [emphasis added]

The possibility of this curious "split/converging etymology" of the English word "air" (and its different meanings) is also mentioned by the [Online Etymology Dictionary/Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=air)

> air (n.1) Look up air at Dictionary.com
>
> [1)] c.1300, "invisible gases that make up the atmosphere," from **Old
>   French air** "atmosphere, breeze, weather" (12c.), from Latin aerem
>   (nominative aer) "air, lower atmosphere, sky," from Greek aer
>   (genitive aeros) "air" (related to aenai "to blow, breathe"), which is
>   of unknown origin, possibly from a base *awer- and thus related to
>   aeirein "to raise" and arteria "windpipe, artery" (see aorta) on
>   notion of "lifting, that which rises." In Homer mostly "thick air,
>   mist;" later "air" as one of the four elements. ...
>
> [2)] 1590s, "manner, appearance" (as in an air of mystery); 1650s,
>   "assumed manner, affected appearance" (especially in phrase put on
>   airs, 1781), from French air "look, appearance, mien, bearing, tone"
>   (**Old French aire** "reality, essence, nature, descent, extraction,"
>   12c.; compare debonair), from Latin ager "place, field" (see acre) on
>   notion of "place of origin."
>
> But **some French sources** connect this **Old French word** ["aire"?]
>   with the source of air (n.1), and it also is possible these senses in
>   English developed from or were influenced by air (n.1); compare sense
>   development of atmosphere and Latin spiritus "breath, breeze," also
>   "high spirit, pride," and the extended senses of anima. air (n.3) Look
>   up air at Dictionary.com
>
> [3)] "melody, tune," 1580s, from Italian aria (see aria)
>   [Emphasis added]

I apologize for taking up so much space here talking about English etymology, and again, I'm not at all claiming that this discussion applies to "air" in French, but the possibility of two different meanings of a single modern word originating from two different source words and merging into the surviving word as the other one disappeared does exist in English and perhaps it can provide you with some insight that will help you find the answer to your interesting question and its edit.

Answer (score 0):

Nul besoin d'avoir un lien. Ce sont simplement différents sens d'un même mot. L'air n'est pas seulement un ensemble gazeux. Air veut aussi dire allure, apparence et en musique, un air est une mélodie.

Comment: merci pour votre réaction mais je me demande justement ce qui justifie cette double définition.

Comment: c'est plus qu'une double définition car nous avons l'air qu'on respire, l'air qu'on se donne et l'air qu'on fredonne. Existe-t-il un lien entre les trois? La question est lancée.